# Black man takes care of girl in the woods

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this film maybe... 10 years ago, it seemed to be late 90s early 2000s, probably American. All I can really distinctly remember is that the black man was basically stuck taking care of a small caucasian girl in his small home in the middle of the woods, and he warned her heavily to NOT go a particular direction, because there was a man (I believe a war veteran) with intense paranoia.

Over the course of the film they bond of course, and near the end of the movie she gets killed by the paranoid man, I believe either by a trap, or by his own gun (he might have been having a war flashback about a young girl in a war trying to kill him), then the black man goes searching for her, and finds the paranoid man freaking out upon realizing he killed an innocent girl, and they cover her body with a blanket and I believe the black man carries her body away. I don't remember the race of the paranoid man, but I believe he was caucasian.

Certainly not *Black Snake Moan*. It's very father-daughter bonding-esque, though it WAS a drama film.

Comment: A lot of it sounds like *Black Snake Moan*, but it's about a young *woman* and the movie doesn't end like that.

Comment: Certainly not... _Black Snake Moan_ is far from it, the film I'm talking about is very father-daughter bonding Esque, though it WAS a drama film, clearly.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Added & posting a possible match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the plot of the 2005 drama [Missing In America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_in_America).

> **Jake (played by Danny Glover), a reclusive Vietnam War veteran, has lived in a cabin in the woods** of the Pacific Northwest for 35 years, plagued with guilt over the loss of men under his command. His only interaction with other people is when he drives into town to sell firewood and buy supplies from Kate (played by Linda Hamilton). **His life is changed when** he is visited by **Henry, an ex-platoon member** (played by David Strathairn). Henry is dying of lung cancer caused by the exposure to Agent Orange, and **entrusts the care of his half-Vietnamese daughter Lenny to Jake.**
>
> Jake refuses, but Henry leaves in the night, leaving his daughter behind and giving Jake little choice but to look after her. Lenny proves troublesome for Jake, and interrupts his normal way of life. Over time however, Lenny encourages Jake to reach out to other Vietnam veterans who are living nearby in self-imposed exile.

That backfires when a booby trap set by one of those veterans, a deeply disturbed man named Red (played by Ron Perlman) is triggered and Lenny is sadly shot dead. Here's the trailer: